# Tag Request: OSB (Oriented Strand Board)

Tags: feature-request, tags, tagging

Please create the tag:

OSB (Oriented Strand Board)

Answer (score 1):

That's a good suggestion for a tag. I am surprised it has not been created before. Tags can be created by Users with sufficient reputation(1,500).  I suggest that you create a question using a tag like plywood and add a comment requesting a user provide the OSB tag you need.  I am sure someone will pick up on that and edit the tags to create the new one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I did as you advised and it looks like the tag has been created.