# Tag Request: Sheds Workshops Tiny Homes

Tags: feature-request, tags, tagging

Please create a tag/tags for those with questions about these popular topics touching the woodworking arena:

- Sheds
- Workshops
- Tiny Homes

They are all related and perhaps the can go under an umbrella term like

***outbuildings***

which could encompass sheds, microshops, garages, tiny homes, greenhouses, gazebos, etc.

Comment: OK, the process for creating new tags was discussed yesterday in https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395/tag-request-osb-oriented-strand-board There are many possible tags that may or may not be used on the site.  They are created when needed.